# URL, GET, POST parameters in Django

Tags: python, django

I am super fresh in Django, I might need some help.

**Case:**

I made endpoint in urls.py. There will be pass latitude and long to his endpoint as parameters.

```
router.register(
    r'name', views.NameView, base_name='name')


urlpatterns = [
    path('name/', views.NameView.as_view(), name='getLocation')
]
```

**What I want to achieve:**

View connected to the endpoint take the parameters and passes it to the '.../product' API and it receive the data and return the data to front end.

I have read a lot about request, but I am confused.
 This is my view:

```
class NameView(views.ModelViewSet):

    def getLocation(Location):
    # here I want to GET with params in URL
        r = requests.get(url, params=Location)

    # POST to URL and next should receive data and send to front
        r = requests.post(url, params=Location)
```

I used Location, beacuse I have definied class in model Location with lat and long params.

I will appreciate any help

Comment: Instead of `getLocation` implement `get`, `post`,... As shown in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Comment: ok, I'll do that, thanks